# How to Iterate through Vector of Vectors and Display the output in cpp

Tags: class, vector, c++98

I have created a simple class with two variables

```
class myclass
{
    string Var1;
    string Var2;
};
```

Now I have created a vector which stores multiple objects of this class

```
vector <myclass> myvector;
```

Now I will create one more vector which will have contain the group of vectors(i.e vector of vectors)

```
vector <vector <myclass>> myvectorofvectors;
```

Now I need a way to read each elements and print on output screen, how can I achieve this in C++98?

Comment: for(auto vec : myvectorofvectors) { for (auto myclassobj  : vec) { //---print }}

Comment: @user1438832 A C++98 standard answer would be better...

Comment: for (std::vector <vector <myclass>>::iterator it = myvectorofvectors.begin() ; it != myvectorofvectors.end(); ++it)
{
 for(std::vector<myclass>::iterator it1 = (*it).begin() ; it1 != (*it).end(); ++it1)
 {
  //-----print *it1 is myclass object
 }
}

Comment: @user1438832 Tested,, iterator it1 doesn't contain any values,on debugging I found, {Var1=<Bad Ptr> Var2=<Bad Ptr> }

Comment: How you print to the output.

Comment: @user1438832 I didn't have any statement inside the loop, for(std::vector<myclass>::iterator it1 = (*it).begin() ; it1 != (*it).end(); ++it1) {     },   while debugging, on iterating this loop ,I just hovered over it1, and found it to be {Var1=<Bad Ptr> Var2=<Bad Ptr> }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++98 use:

```
    vector< vector<myclass> >::iterator row;
    vector<myclass>::iterator col;

    for (row = myvectorofvectors.begin(); row != myvectorofvectors.end(); row++) {
        for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
            // do stuff ...
        }
    }
```